# Can't resize UITextField in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a UITextField in an Xcode storyboard, with horizontal alignment to centre and a top and bottom alignment:

[image]

however the field is too small, so I changed the width. I keep the horizontal align to centre so it's not using numerical values like this:

[image]

However, when I run, or press Editor > Update Frames, I notice that the field shrinks again! The width returns to 25. How can I keep the width wide, say 250, without it reverting??

Comment: apply width constraint !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a width constraint to it, otherwise it just has it's intrinsic size. Press`ctrl` and drag a horizontal line from the field to itself. You can then adjust the `constant` value of this constraint.

Comment: Ah solved thanks! (will accept in 5 when I can). Does this mean the width field that I screenshotted above is simply for my own view and not for the programs determination of the width?

Comment: Yes, the real frame is that orange dashed rectangle. If you don't specify the size, views like UIBtton, UILabel, UIImageView will calculate it themselves, based on their content. You can change this size with explicit constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a placeholder text to it like "Enter text here..." in attributes inspector > Placeholder. 
It changes the TextField intrinsic content size and allows you to see the result without need to add constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Update constraint instead of Update Frames.

[image]